# Django upload_to outside of MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: python, django, security, upload, media

My deployment script overwrites the media and source directories which means I have to move the uploads directory out of the media directory, and replace it after the upload has been extracted.

How can I instruct django to upload to /uploads/ instead of /media/?

So far I keep getting django Suspicious Operation errors! :(

I suppose another solution might be a symlink?

Many thanks,
Toby.

Comment: More importantly, why is your deployment script overwriting uploaded content?

Comment: It's not overwriting the uploads because I copy the dir out of the media dir first. Im trying to upload to a different directory so I can overwrite media without having to move uploads.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I did the following:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

upload_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=UPLOAD_ROOT, base_url='/uploads')

image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/images', storage=upload_storage)
```

`UPLOAD_ROOT` is defined in my `settings.py` file: `/foo/bar/webfolder/uploads`

Comment: nice job. i just played with django filefields in an application i'm writing for work. i may end up going this route as well.

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer is probably what you want, we now have the option with `django` 3.1 that we can decide which storage to use at runtime by passing a function to the storage argument of an `ImageField` or `FileField`.

```
def select_storage():
    return MyLocalStorage() if settings.DEBUG else MyRemoteStorage()


class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_file = models.FileField(storage=select_storage)
```

Have a look at the official [docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/#using-a-callable)

Please note that the current accepted answer writes the actual value of the variable `UPLOAD_ROOT` to the migration file. This doesn't produce any `SQL` when you apply it to the database but may be confusing if you change that setting frequently.

Comment: If you have a different UPLOAD_ROOT on production, it could say "you have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration", what is not really a thing you'd want to see when calling `manage.py migrate` on production?