# How to change the default media url for a in django file field?

Tags: django

I am using `django-sendfile` to protect certain files.

The problem is that when the file is displayed on the frontend it uses the `MEDIA_ROOT` location which is not where the file actually is.

[image: Admin leave file link]

[image: Frontend leave file link]

The actual link (that checks permissions) that I want to use is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/leave/supporting_doc/57
```

yet the link displayed is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/leave/user_2/2018-09-06-logo.png
```

The field in the model is:

```
supporting_doc = models.FileField(
    upload_to=user_leave_directory_path,
    storage=SENDFILE_STORAGE,
    blank=True,
    validators=[FileExtensionValidator(ACCEPTED_FILE_TYPES)]
)
```

The upload to method give a link relative to `MEDIA_ROOT`:

```
def user_leave_directory_path(instance, filename):
    '''Get the user directory for leave supporting document'''
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'leave/user_'\
        f'{instance.user.id}/{instance.start_date}-{filename}'
```

Comment: You need to fix your `MEDIA_URL` setting if the URL being generated is incorrect. Looks like `MEDIA_URL` needs to be set to `/media/`.

Comment: The question is a bit more complex because I am uploading to protected locations using `django-sendfile`, The outputted url is correct for non-protected media.

Comment: This thread might have a hint - maybe you need to configure or override SENDFILE_STORAGE to not use MEDIA_ROOT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729051/django-upload-to-outside-of-media-root

Comment: Yes that works to give the actual protected location on the server. I'm just trying to override the whole thing with a custom url.