# Setting multiple MEDIA_URL & MEDIA_ROOT in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-media

I've set Static and Media root as well as url's in my django app, as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

MEDIA_URL = '/crl/'
MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'config/crl/')
```

It is working great, but I want to add another MEDIA_URL & MEDIA_ROOT to serve files from the `/certs/` directory as follows:

```
NEW_MEDIA_URL = '/certs/'
NEW_MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'config/certs/')
```

Is there any way to do it?
I'm using Django 2.0.6 and Python 3.5

Comment: You can use a custom file storage for that. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729051/django-upload-to-outside-of-media-root) for an example.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks for the comment, I'll use that.

Comment: @hoefling will it work for download also?

Comment: If you configure the urlpatterns correctly, it should work, there's no magic behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple static URLs and static roots can be added to Django using the following steps.

1. Configure a `BASE_DIR`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
```

2. Create as many static roots and static URLs as you need

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
# the "static/" above is a directory inside the Django Project Directory

STATIC_URL_1 = '/static-1/'
STATIC_ROOT_1 = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_1/")
```

3. Similarly, you can create as many media roots and media URLs as you need

```
MEDIA_URL = '/crl/'
MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'config/crl/')

MEDIA_URL_1 = '/crl-1/'
MEDIA_ROOT_1  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'config/crl_1/')
```